# Using Oracle SQL, how can I get weekdays (Monday-Sunday) using their rank (1-7)?

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle, here is my problem :

**What I have:**

A number between 1 and 7.

**What I want:**

1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday...

**What I did so far:**

DECODE(myVar,1,'Monday',2,'Tuesday',...)

I have of course thought of writing a function but I would like to know if there is no native way to do that.

EDIT : Since it seems unclear, I want a native way to do this without using a DECODE or a CASE.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula will produce what you want:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') +
               (CAST(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW'), 'D') AS NUMBER) +
               :DAY_OF_WEEK - 3), 'Day')
  FROM DUAL
```

To use, replace the :DAY_OF_WEEK parameter with whatever value you want and it will return the day of the week.

Comment: I tried this with :DAY_OF_WEEK = 1 and it gave me Tuesday (note that my NLS Settings are in French, but I was expecting Sunday or Monday). Care to explain why ?

Comment: I don't know why this happened. For me, when I use 1 as DAY_OF_WEEK it returns 'Monday'. [dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=14aa359d7a983b03ed9157c2fce1fa92)

Comment: @MonsieurTruite - what does `SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'D') FROM DUAL` return on your system? For me it returns 14-Oct-2018.

Comment: https://rextester.com/ZKZ66574 brings me tuesday.
For your second question : 20181015 for me !
Your help is appreciated though.

Comment: @MonsieurTruite: I've updated the formula to handle use international week settings instead of locale-specific week settings. [dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7b91ceb6ebc69d5db075207a1356d153). Give it another try.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Good answer.  But is it really better than `DECODE(l_day,1,'Monday',2,'Tuesday',...)`?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak It could be a fast way to avoid problems with 'Monday' / 'Mon' / 'MONDAY'...?

Comment: @MonsieurTruite: I'd think that this formula would return the correct name-of-day if the database is localized for a non-English language, e.g. lundi, mardi, mercredi, etc for French localization, Montag, Dienstag, Mittwoch, usw for German, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use to_char function with the `Day` and `D` arguments for a date variable as in the following :

```
SQL> var day_nr number;
SQL> exec :day_nr := 1;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
day_nr
---------
1

SQL> alter session set NLS_TERRITORY="UNITED KINGDOM";
SQL> with t(day,day_nr) as
  2  (
  3   select to_char(level + sysdate,'Day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'),
  4          to_char(level + sysdate,'D')
  5     from dual
  6  connect by level <= 7
  7  )
  8  select day
  9    from t
 10   where day_nr = :day_nr;

DAY
---------
Monday
```

As an example, if you substitute `1` for `:day_nr` you get `Monday` etc.

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/BTSWC66763)

*P.S. thanks to @Matthew McPeak I realize that the returning value for `to_char(<date>,'D')` may differ from TERRITORY, for example, it differs whether `NLS_TERRITORY` parameter is set "UNITED KINGDOM" or "AMERICAN_AMERICA".*

Comment: I think maybe you are getting lucky that your solution works where you live.  The day of the week numbering depends on `NLS_TERRITORY`, not `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`.  See: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A.  When I run your example in my database with `day_nr=1`, I get "Sunday".

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak exactly, you're right, edited the `NLS_TERRITORY` parameter. Thanks so much.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I chose Bob's answer because it was shorter (in terms of characters, let's say), but your solution also does the job. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[TO_DATE](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) has a format_mask that allows you to create a date from the numeric day of the week. Then you could get the weekday name from that. However it requires a string input.

Answer (score 0):

this will surely work as you have asked a function without decode or case:

```
declare
a varchar(20);
b varchar(20);
c varchar(20);
d varchar(20);
e varchar(20);
f varchar(20);
g varchar(20);
h varchar(20);
i number;
begin
i:=&i;
SELECT COALESCE((select 'null' from dual where i<>1),'MONDAY')into a from dual;
SELECT COALESCE((select 'null' from dual where i<>2),'TUEDAY')into b from dual;
SELECT COALESCE((select 'null' from dual where i<>3),'WEDNESDAY') into c from dual;
SELECT COALESCE((select 'null' from dual where i<>4),'THURDAY') into d from dual;
SELECT COALESCE((select 'null' from dual where i<>5),'FRIDAY')into e from dual;
SELECT COALESCE((select 'null' from dual where i<>6),'SATURDAY')into f from dual;
SELECT COALESCE((select 'null' from dual where i<>7),'SUNDAY')into g from dual;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(a||b||c||d||e||f||g);

end;
/
```

for input of 4 output is:

```
null  null null  THURDAY  null null null
```